# Inserting into or Creating a table from one table and one view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to either create a new table or insert into a currently existing one. The data I need is contained in two seperate places. One is a table, we'll call it T and it contains one column of data which we'll call HEXID. The other is a view which contains many columns, only three of which are relevant to my problem. We'll call the view V and the relevant columns ID, MID, and NAME. As I said, I'd like to create either a new table (or a new view) which should look something like this:

```
+---------+------+-------+--------+
| T.HEXID | V.ID | V.MID | V.NAME |   
+---------+------+-------+--------+
| DATA    | DATA | DATA  | DATA   |
+---------+------+-------+--------+
```

There is a significant amount of data here. We're talking 10s of 1000s of rows. I've been trying to do this for several days but SQL Developer doesn't seem to want to cooperate. So, what I'd like to know is:

1. Is  this possible?
2. If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: . . Can you provide an example of input data and desired results?  You don't explain how to match the data in the two tables.

Comment: "10s of 1000s of rows" does not qualfiy as *significant amount of data*

Comment: @GordonLinoff, T.HEXID would be something like 0x000ABCDE, V.ID would be something like 1234567, V.MID would be something like 7654321, and V.NAME would be something like This-IsAnElement-0.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(id NUMBER, col1 NUMBER);
-- table TAB1 created.
CREATE TABLE tab2(id NUMBER, col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER, col3 NUMBER);
-- table TAB2 created.

INSERT  ALL
INTO tab1(id, col1)             VALUES (tab1_id, tab1_col1)
INTO tab2(id, col1, col2, col3) VALUES (tab2_id, tab2_col1, tab2_col2, tab2_col3)
SELECT  1  AS tab1_id
,       11 AS tab1_col1
,       1  AS tab2_id
,       21 AS tab2_col1
,       22 AS tab2_col2
,       23 AS tab2_col3
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2 rows inserted.

SELECT * FROM tab1;
-- 1    11

SELECT * FROM tab2;
-- 1    21  22  23

CREATE  VIEW tab_vw AS
SELECT  tab1.id   AS tab1_id
,       tab1.col1 AS tab1_col1
,       tab2.id   AS tab2_id
,       tab2.col1 AS tab2_col1
,       tab2.col2 AS tab2_col2
,       tab2.col3 AS tab2_col3
FROM    tab1
JOIN    tab2
ON      tab1.id = tab2.id
;
-- view TAB_VW created.

SELECT * FROM tab_vw;
-- 1    11  1   21  22  23

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tab_trg
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON tab_vw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tab1(id, col1)             VALUES (:new.tab1_id, :new.tab1_col1);
    INSERT INTO tab2(id, col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:new.tab2_id, :new.tab2_col1, :new.tab2_col2, :new.tab2_col3);
END;
-- TRIGGER TAB_TRG compiled

INSERT  INTO tab_vw
(
        tab1_id
,       tab1_col1
,       tab2_id
,       tab2_col1
,       tab2_col2
,       tab2_col3
)
SELECT  2  AS tab1_id
,       11 AS tab1_col1
,       2  AS tab2_id
,       21 AS tab2_col1
,       22 AS tab2_col2
,       23 AS tab2_col3
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 1 rows inserted.

SELECT  *
FROM    tab_vw;
-- 1    11  1   21  22  23
-- 2    11  2   21  22  23
```